# How to disassemble using metasm?

Tags: disassembly, tools

I just can't figure out how to disassemble an `.exe` file using [metasm](http://metasm.cr0.org/). As far as I know the command should look something like:

```
ruby disassemble.rb [path-to-my-exe-file] > [path-to-output.asm]
```

But, that's not quite the thing.

Comment: How exactly not? [An otherwise uninformed Google search](https://www.pentestgeek.com/2012/01/25/using-metasm-to-avoid-antivirus-detection-ghost-writing-asm/) suggests `ruby ~/tools/metasploit/lib/metasm/samples/disassemble.rb raw_binary > asm_code.asm`, which contains the full path to `disassembly.rb`.

Comment: The disassemble.rb has in line 13 "require 'metasm'" and the error I get says "cannot load such file -- metasm (LoadError)"

Comment: @SiltCrawler  Do you have metasm installed?  That's what that error says to me; Ruby can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is quite easy.

```
ruby disassemble.rb [path-to-my-exe-file] > [path-to-output.asm]
```

Is totally fine. I didn't copy `metasm.rb` and the `metasm` subfolder to the `[ruby_dir]/lib/ruby/[version_number]/` directory.